How can I test logic that integrates with early Spring bootstrapping?
I am trying to prevent my spring boot application to start if I consider two or more active profiles to be conflicting. I.e. dev and prod should not be active at the same time.
Moreover, I want to make sure this logic and its integration into Spring bootstrapping code is properly tested.
I tried EnvironmentPostProcessor as well as ApplicationEvent<ApplicationEnvironmentPrepared>, I have annotated the test with @SpringBootTest and I use assertThrows in the test method.
If I do new AnnotationApplicationContext() I don't seem to find a way to manipulate the environment used by the context and if I try to SpringApplication.run() a test application myself, it doesn't seem to be able to find any injectable bean for environment at all.
I am pretty sure I am trying the wrong things and maybe there's an easier way to achieve my goal anyway. Any hints or pointers would be greatly appreciated.
@Bean
public ApplicationListener<ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent> ensureNonConflictingProfiles() {
    return event -> {
        if (event.getEnvironment().getActiveProfiles().length > 1) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Only one of the profiles can be active");
        }
    };
}


have you written the logic that prevents start in case of conflicting profiles? If yes please provide it and I will be able to tell you how to test it

Code is reading the environment from the event or the parameter of postProcessEnvironment and throwing an IllegalStateException if it finds conflicts. I have a unit test for that already that injects the environment as a mock. However, I'd like to be sure this is e2e hooked up correctly in Spring and hence really fails the application startup.
I tried both @Bean for ApplicationListener and @EventListener for a method receiving the event. On inspection, the listeners are registered in the ApplicationContext - I just don't manage to set the profiles for that context before I create it.

could you provide (add to the question) any of that code you keep talking about?

I added a simplified version that only accepts a single active profile at all times. I don't think this is the problematic piece of code though, as my question is concerned with the integration with Spring's application startup.

Have you tried registering your custom EnvironmentPostprocessor with spring.factories? This can be done by putting the following code in spring.factores file located at META-INF/spring.factories:
org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor=com.example.MyCustomEnvPostProcessor

Now you can create a ProfileConflictTest class as:
@SpringBootTest
class ProfileConflictTest {

    @Test
    void testProfileConflict() {
        assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class,() -> {
            SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(MyApplication.class);
            app.setAdditionalProfiles("dev", "prod");
            app.run();
        });
    }
}


I end up with "No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.core.env.Environment' available" if I try to start a class annotated with @SpringBootApplication this way.

And yes, I have been registering the EnvironmentPostProcessor. Although the need to do that explicitly as configuration led to me thinking about the ApplicationListener approach.

Doesn't @SpringBootTest already bootstrap the Application context? That would prevent the @Test from even starting.

Never mind. I just figured out that having a @Component that was called com.example.whatever.Environment on the classpath led to SpringApplication.run() to fail with No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.core.env.Environment' available but renaming this to e.g. com.example.whatever.Environment1 fixed that problem.

I'd still be curious how this could be introducing a problem as the fully qualified class names are surely different.

Bean names are simple names, there are no "fully qualified bean names". If you keep reading the error, it probably stated "expected exactly 1 bean, but found 2: […, …]"
